# codeigniter:make validation of dynamically created textfield using jquery clone method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, codeigniter

I have following code.

```
    <section class="section_class">
    <input type="text" name="branch_contact_person_name[]" value="<?php echo set_value('branch_contact_person_name'); ?>" placeholder="Branch Contact Person Name" />
    <input type="text" name="branch_contact_person_email[]" value="<?php echo set_value('shop_email'); ?>" placeholder="Branch Contact Person Email" />
    <input type="text" name="branch_contact_person_mobile[]" value="<?php echo set_value('shop_mobile'); ?>" placeholder="Branch Contact Person Mobile" />
    </section>
<input type="hidden" class="add_fields" />
```

And i am using following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_next_branch").click(function() { //add_next_branch is a button
        $('.section_class').clone().appendTo('.add_fields');
    });
});
```

The text fields are creating properly but when i submit form with all text fields blank then it will display proper message but the text fields are which are creating are going off.
this is controller

```
function branch_details() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch_contact_person_name[]', 'Site Name', 'required|xss_clean');
    /*$this->form_validation->set_rules('product_category', 'Product Category', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); //This field is hidden
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_brand','Product Brand','required|greater_than[0]');
    //select location -- $this->form_validation->set_rules('shop_mobile', 'Shop Mobile', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|xss_clean|numeric');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('brand_pic', 'Product Image', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_desc', 'Product Description', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price_type', 'Product Price Type', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_mrp', 'M.R.P ', 'required|xss_clean');
    */
    $data = array();
    $this->load->view('templates/homepage_header');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['action_name'] = 'branch_details';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['action_name'] = 'shop_view';
    }
        $this->load->view('shop_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: What you mean by going off..

Comment: I don't understand your question, but you have a typo, you forgot the closing `"` -> `class="section_class"`

Comment: Going off - i mean to say the element which is appended to add_field is getting removed from DOM

Comment: Your form is getting refreshed when you submit it, hence the cloned fields are not persisting. Could you supply your controller code?

Comment: @philip you are correct my form is getting refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the Cloned Elements like this

```
 function validate()
    {       
        var contact_person_name= document.getElementById('formid').elements["branch_contact_person_name[]"];
        var contact_person_email=document.getElementById('formid').elements["branch_contact_person_email[]"];
        var contact_person_mobile=document.getElementById('formid').elements["branch_contact_person_mobile[]"];

        var length =  contact_person_name.length;

    if(isNaN(length))
    {

        if(contact_person_name.value=='')
        {
            alert('Please enter  name');
                    return false;
        }
        if(contact_person_email.value=='')
        {
            alert('Please enter email');
                    return false;
        }
        if(contact_person_mobile.value=='')
        {
            alert('Please enter Mobileno');
                    return false;
        }
    }

        for (var i = 0; i < contact_person_name.length; i++)
      {

            if (contact_person_name[i].value== '') {
                alert('Please enter name.');
                return false;
            }
        if (contact_person_email[i].value== '') {
                alert('Please enter email.');
                return false;
            }
        if (contact_person_mobile[i].value== '') {
                alert('Please enter mobile.');
                return false;
            }
    }
    document.yourform.submit();
    }
```

Make sure declare id for your `HTML` form .This was might be helpful to you.Thanks